# ¿Cómo soluciono este "ValueError: unknown url type: 'h'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy corriendo un programa que va checkeando URLs desde un archivo de texto, intentando conectarse a ellas.
Si no puede conectarse, pasa a la siguiente URL, pero si logra conectarse añade ésta URL a otro archivo de texto.

Cuando corro esta secuencia: [image: Codigo]

.
.

Me da este error: [image: Error]

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: de preferencia que el codigo y los errores sea texto es mas facil para hacer pruebas

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error nos dice:

> Tipo de url desconocido: 'h,'

Efectivamente "h" no es ninguna url válida, la causa está en la línea:

```
link = file.readline(count)
```

`readline` puede recibir un argumento opcional que indica el número de bytes/caracteres que debe retornar, no indica el número de línea que queremos.

Imaginemos el siguiente archivo:

> hola
>   mundo

Si después de abrir el archivo hacemos:

```
>>> file.readline(3)
'hol'
```

¿Por qué retorna `'hol'` y no la línea completa? Bien, esto pasa porque al pasarle `3` como argumento le indicamos que nos retorne 3 bytes/caracteres desde la posición actual del cursor o hasta un carácter de nueva línea, lo que antes ocurra.

Si seguimos llamando lo podemos ver más claro:

```
>>> file.readline(3)
'hol'  
>>> file.readline(3)
'a\n' 
>>> file.readline(3)
'mun' 
>>> file.readline(3)
'do\n'
```

Si queremos iterar sobre todo el fichero, podemos romper el ciclo usando un condicional aprovechando que `readline` retorna una cadena vacía cuando esto ocurre:

```
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        break
```

De todas formas lo anterior no tiene sentido, iterar con un `for` sobre el fichero nos permite obtener las líneas de forma más simple y mucho más eficiente que un `while` + `readline`.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error


with open("UNCHECKEDLINKS.txt") as file,\
     open("linkdatabase.txt", "a") as link_data_base:

    for line in file:
        url = line.rstrip()
        print('Testing "{}"...'.format(url))

        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen(url)

        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            print("  [ERROR  ]: The server couldn`t fulfill the request")

        except urllib.error.URLError:
            print("  [ERROR  ]: We failed to reach a server")

        except ValueError:
            print("  [ERROR  ]: Malformed URL")

        else:
            link_data_base.write(line)
            print("  [SUCCESS]: The url exists")
```

Para un fichero de entrada:

> https://stackoverflow.com
>   https://www.noexisto.net
>   https://www.python.org
>   no soy una url

obtenemos el siguiente de salida:

> https://stackoverflow.com
>   https://www.python.org

y la siguiente salida vía salida estándar:

```
Testing "https://stackoverflow.com"...
  [SUCCESS]: The url exists
Testing "https://www.noexisto.net"...
  [ERROR  ]: We failed to reach a server
Testing "https://www.python.org"...
  [SUCCESS]: The url exists
Testing "no soy una url"...
  [ERROR  ]: Malformed URL
```